Elevation Profile Tool Flip the Direction of View
Is there any way to flip the direction of the profile display in QGIS Elevation Profile tool?
If you have an alignment that goes East to West and you want to display that elevation profile in your map over the alignment and have them co-aligned, how do you do that?  As you can see below, my alignment runs west but the profile for it runs left to right.  How do I reverse that?

